# Enabling push notification with React.js and signalR

Tags: reactjs, push-notification, signalr, asp.net-core-signalr

I need to enable pushnotifications using signalR

```
      import { HubConnectionBuilder} from '@microsoft/signalr';
      import jwt_decode from "jwt-decode";

      let connection = null;

    export function setupSignalRConnection(onNotificationReceived ) {
    debugger
    const token = localStorage.getItem("token");
    let userId = "";

    if (token) {
    const decodedToken = jwt_decode(token);
    userId = decodedToken.UserId;
    console.log(userId);
    }
    connection = new HubConnectionBuilder()
    .withUrl(('http://123.456.789.365/ExampleURL/NotificationUserHub?userId=${userId}'),
    {
        // skipNegotiation: true,
        // transport: signalR.HttpTransportType.WebSockets,
        timeout: 3000000,
        queryString: `userId=${userId}`,
    })
    .withAutomaticReconnect()
    .build();
 
  connection.start()
    .then(() => {
      const connectionId = connection.connectionId;
      console.log('Connected to SignalR hub. Connection ID:',connectionId);
      localStorage.setItem('signalrConnection',JSON.stringify(connection));
      // Perform any necessary actions after connection establishment
    })
    .catch(error => console.error(error));

    connection.on("sendToParent", (notification) => {
      console.log('Received notification:', notification);
      onNotificationReceived(notification);
    });

    connection.on("sendToEmployee", (notification) => {
      console.log('Send notification:', notification);
      onNotificationReceived(notification);
    });

  return connection;
}
```

Now i am successfully getting connected, but i am not receiving notifications when some action is taken place.Is this code correct or shall i add something extra to make it work correctly, please suggest if this code have any fixes.

Answer (score 0):

You should add methods name `sendToEmployee_backend` and `sendToParent_backend` inside your `NotificationUserHub` class.

Like below:

```
    public async Task sendToEmployee_backend()
    {
        //List<string?> data = ConnectedUsers.Keys.ToList();
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("sendToEmployee", data);
    }
    public async Task sendToParent_backend()
    {
        //List<string?> data = ConnectedUsers.Keys.ToList();
        await Clients.All.SendAsync("sendToParent", data);
    }
```

You could DI the hub in your controller for testing, like below.

```
public class TestController : Controller
{
    private readonly ILogger<TestController> _logger;
    private readonly IHubContext<MainHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly MainHub _hub;

    public TestController(ILogger<TestController> logger, IHubContext<MainHub> hubcontext, MainHub hub)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _hubContext = hubcontext;
        _hub = hub;
    }
    public IActionResult Check()
    {
        _hub.sendToEmployee_backend();
        _hub.sendToParent_backend();

        return Ok("Success");
    }
}
```